# How to pass value from <option><select> to method of Rails-controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to share my problem with you.

How to pass value from `<option><select>` - to this or that, depending on select, method of Rails-controller?
If id of (or name) selected is 'one', it should be passed to method 'def one'.
If id of selected is 'two', it should be passed to 'def two'.
etc

I want to remove 'case' from my controller:

```
def index

case
when params[:select_action] == 'one'
something
when params[:select_action] == 'two'
something
----

end
```

How to solve this puzzle? Thank you for your answer.

Form:

```
<select id="select_action" name="select_action">
<option value="one">One</option>
<option value="two">Two</option>
<option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

ajax:

```
function call() {
$('#Submit').prop('disabled', true);
var msg   = $('#form').serialize();
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/targets',
data: msg,
success: function(data) {
$('#Submit').prop('disabled', false);
}
});
}
```

controller:

```
def one
...
end
def two
...
end
def three
...
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :targets
devise_for :users
root to: 'targets#index'
end
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! In order to help, we'll need some more information. Also, take a look bath the [ask] page to get some tips. Most helpful would be if you could give some code samples of what you have already tried (particularly your view and your controller).

Comment: Ok, thank you. Has been updated.

Comment: Could you also include the relevant portion of your routes file?

Comment: Ok. Of course. Updated.

Comment: Could your question be rephrased like this: "How do I route to a controller method other than `#show` based on contents of (serialized) form data?"

Comment: Ok, I updated the description of my problem. Tell me please, is my task clear now?

Comment: Yep, I think I can answer it now :)

Comment: It would be cool...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way  you have it now with the case statement is actually the most common way I've seen this done, with a slight modification:

```
def index
  case params[:select_action]
  when 'one'
    one
  when 'two'
    two
  end
end
```

This is fairly readable, and works for most cases. However, if you want to move this logic out of the controller entirely, you could do so with a [routing constraint](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints):

```
# you can create a constraint object to perform the match
ParamMatchContraint = Struct.new(:parameter, :expected_value) do
  def matches?(request)
    request.params[parameter] == expected_value
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :targets do
    # a lambda will work as well as a constraint class
    root constraints: lambda {|request| request.params[:select_action] == 'one'}, action: :one
    root constraints: ParamMatchContraint.new(:select_ation, 'two'), action: :two
  end
  ...
end
```

Note though that this is an "opt in" constraint, and anything that doesn't match will fall through to the index action.

This is also a fairly novel thing to do, so newbies to the project could easily get tripped up by this. However, it very well could be the best way to accomplish your task. What you get from this method is that filters using `only` and `except` can specify your custom actions, and you can use the default conventions for specifying views based on action name with out having to manually specify a view file.